# How to read a big file(bigger than 1 billion) with Chunk

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dask, chunking

I have a dataset bigger than 1 billion rows and I would like to read it by 100k rows. First I have tried to read it with nrows as below:

```
df = pd.read_csv("filename.csv",nrows=100000,sep='|')
```

But it throws an `UnicodeDecodeError` as below.

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc9 in position 3: unexpected end of data
```

Then I tried it with `chunksize` parameter as below:

```
a= pd.read_csv("filename.csv", chunksize=10000,sep='|')
pd.concat(a)
```

But it gives same error to me. I have also tried Dask library as below but it gives same error.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.read_csv('filename.csv')
```

Can you please help for the solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your file is not in UTF-8 character set.  Do you know what character set it is?

Comment: I don't know actually, Do you know how to check? I use mac.

Comment: You need to KNOW this.  If you look at the first few rows in an editor, you should be able to tell if there are non-ASCII characters.  Where did the file come from?

Comment: You can upload a file with about first 10 rows. If there are some important data in it, you can replace them with some random data but keep same type and encode.

Comment: UTF8 and all other single-byte codepages are *identical* for characters in the range 0-127, which includes English characters. Obviously your file contains *non*-English characters. In what language? Have you tried using the codepage that matches the language? Latin1/iso-8859-1 covers most European languages. Turkish? Cyrillic?

Comment: It's in Turkish, I will try codepage as you said.

Comment: The real fix would be to tell whoever produced the file to use UTF8 in the future. It's not a *new* encoding. All computes outside the US and Western Europe *depend* on Unicode for the last 21 years at least - Windows strings since Windows NT are Unicode. Mangled text due to codepage incompatibilities were a problem in the 1990s but largely disappeared since Windows 2000 and Unicode languages like Java, C#, Javascript and VB.NET became popular. Even VB6 had Unicode strings (but no UTF8)

Comment: OK, Turkish is ISO8859-9, so try `df = pd.read_csv("filename.csv", nrows=100000, sep="|", encoding="iso8859-9")`.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was as below :

```
df = pd.read_csv("filename.csv", nrows=100000, sep="|", encoding="iso8859-9")
```